# How to detect the position of this QR code like object and split in cells?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have already succeeded generating the following output image from my input image using four-point transformation and thresholding:

[image: Output image after four-point transformation and thresholding]

After that, I used template matching to determine the orientation points:

[image: Output image after template matching with marked orientation points]

Would it be best to search for the 3 points with the largest distance? What is the best way to do that I always find the right and bottom side and align the image accordingly?

I also don't know yet how to divide the image into cells, so that I can detect in which cell a dot is.

Divide the image into 31x31 equal parts I have already tried, but this does not always fit, and there were cells where half of 2 points were visible. But this leads to problems with the later color recognition.

Comment: have a look at the bottom of the document, at section "Detector Parameters" which gives you an insight on how to do it  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, your actual marker has dimensions `(25, 25)`!? Where does the `(31, 31)` come from?

Cropping the actual marker from the image, and resizing to `(25, 25)` seems to be sufficient.

For the orientation, you can simply check all four corners for which is `0`, and rotate accordingly.

Here's some code and visualization:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def extract_marker(image, marker_size):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(image)
    image = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    return cv2.threshold(cv2.resize(image, marker_size),
                         128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]


def correct_marker_orientation(marker):
    empty = np.argwhere(marker[[0, -1, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1, -1]] == 0).item()
    if empty > 0:
        marker = cv2.rotate(marker, empty - 1)
    return marker


img_orig = cv2.imread('zHxrv.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_rot90 = cv2.rotate(img_orig, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
img_rot180 = cv2.rotate(img_orig, cv2.ROTATE_180)
img_rot270 = cv2.rotate(img_orig, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 9))
for i_i, img in enumerate([img_orig, img_rot90, img_rot180, img_rot270]):
    m = extract_marker(img, (25, 25))
    m_corr = correct_marker_orientation(m)
    plt.subplot(3, 4, i_i + 1), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.subplot(3, 4, i_i + 5), plt.imshow(m, cmap='gray')
    plt.subplot(3, 4, i_i + 9), plt.imshow(m_corr, cmap='gray')
plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

I assumed, the `0` corner to be located top left.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Matplotlib:    3.4.2
NumPy:         1.19.5
OpenCV:        4.5.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for.

I had 31x31 with the border, that was my mistake and resizing it to 25x25 pixels also simplifies a lot.

Thank you very much.